# How to make parallax background transparent

Tags: css, background, project, parallax

I am working on a school project in which I need to create an informational website using html and css. I am not allowed to use script tags or a javascript file because this is on code.org.
I have succeeded in making a parallax effect, but the only issue is that the page that comes already has the same background as the fixed one. Take a look at the website below.

[Project](https://codeprojects.org/projects/weblab/7zvpjdXADW0rqrmXX1YH2ea-ZrHo9mfrrpVrjwE9e5s)

If you scroll, the page comes up but with a background.
I am trying to make the background transparent.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(paper.jpg);
  font-family: 'Kalam';
}

p {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.parallax {
  background-image: linear-gradient();
  min-height: 600px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.glow {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes glow {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #009fd2, 0 0 40px #009fd2, 0 0 50px #009fd2, 0 0 60px #009fd2, 0 0 70px #009fd2;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #4da3ff, 0 0 40px #4da3ff, 0 0 50px #4da3ff, 0 0 60px #4da3ff, 0 0 70px #4da3ff, 0 0 80px #ff4da6;
  }
}

li {
  font-size: 2
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kalam' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>TikTok Better</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parallax"></div>

  <center>
    <h1 class="glow">
      <img src="giphy.gif" alt="TikTok Logo" style="float:right;width:80px;height:80px;">
      <img src="Youtube_shorts_icon.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:left;width:45px;height:50px;"> Why YouTube shorts sucks
    </h1>
  </center>


  <h2>Reasons:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li>It's a ripoff of TikTok.</li>
    <li>Its clearly the same layout and function of TikTok.</li>
    <li>The videos are outdated.</li>
    <li>The videos suck.</li>
  </ol>
  <h2>Memes</h2>
  <ul>
    <p>
      <li>
        <b>YouTube: </b>They're all clearly outdated by at least 1 year. Most them aren't even funny.
      </li>
    </p>

    <p>
      <li>
        <b>TikTok: </b>The memes are all up to date and funny.
      </li>
    </p>
  </ul>
  <h2>Layout</h2>
  <ul>
    <p>
    </p>
    <li>
      <b>YouTube: </b>Just hideous. Basically exactly the same as TikTok with minimal differences. The like button and live streams are all there.
    </li>
    <p></p>
    <p>
    </p>
    <li>
      <b>TikTok: </b>The original nice and easy look. Everything is in thumb reach and is in dark mode so it's easy on your eyes.
    </li>
    <p></p>
  </ul>
  <h2>People On The Platform</h2>
  <ul>
    <p>
      <li>
        <b>YouTube: </b> Random people people getting views off clickbait and whatnot
      </li>
    </p>
    <p>
      <li>
        <b>TikTok: </b> All respected people like music artists and others.
      </li>
    </p>
  </ul>
  <h2>Further Explanation</h2>
  <p>We can clearly see that YouTube Shorts was created after TikTok. All the videos are also super boring and most of them use outdated memes. Check out this link for a comparison:
    <a href="https://nationalpositions.com/youtube-shorts-vs-tiktok-whats-the-difference/">Comparison</a>. There is a very nice video explaining if YouTube should stop makeing shorts. It gives opinions on both sides with clear and concise detail. Take
    a look: <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaETvTFJ4rc">Opinions.</a>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

If anybody could help, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Randy

I've tried removing the background by using background-color: transparent;
but all it does is make it into a regular scrolling page.
I've also tried adjusting the opacity, but it also just breaks the parallax effect.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: A quick look at your page shows that your page is thoroughly invalid. The validator reports 7 errors and then gives up.

Comment: I added some code snippets. Is it good now?

Answer (score 0):

Move all of the information inside of the
`<div class="parallax">` this will make the background of these things the background of the site.

If you still want them lower on the page create a new element above them that takes up the space.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kalam' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>TikTok Better</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parallax">

        put a div here that takes up space 


        <center>
      <h1 class="glow">
        <img src="giphy.gif" alt="TikTok Logo" style="float:right;width:80px;height:80px;">
        <img src="Youtube_shorts_icon.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:left;width:45px;height:50px;">
        Why YouTube shorts sucks
      </h1>
    </center>


    <h2>Reasons:</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>It's a ripoff of TikTok.</li>
      <li>Its clearly the same layout and function of TikTok.</li>
      <li>The videos are outdated.</li>
      <li>The videos suck.</li>
    </ol>
    <h2>Memes</h2>
    <ul>
      <p>   
        <li>
          <b>YouTube: </b>They're all clearly outdated by at least 1 year. Most them aren't even funny.
        </li>
      </p>

      <p>
        <li>
          <b>TikTok: </b>The memes are all up to date and funny.
        </li>
      </p>
    </ul>
    <h2>Layout</h2>
    <ul>
      <p>
      </p><li>
      <b>YouTube: </b>Just hideous. Basically exactly the same as TikTok with minimal differences. The like button and live streams are all there.
      </li>
      <p></p>
      <p>
      </p><li>
      <b>TikTok: </b>The original nice and easy look. Everything is in thumb reach and is in dark mode so it's easy on your eyes.
      </li>
      <p></p>
    </ul>
    <h2>People On The Platform</h2>
    <ul>
      <p> 
        <li>
          <b>YouTube: </b> Random people people getting views off clickbait and whatnot
        </li>
      </p>
      <p>  
        <li>
          <b>TikTok: </b> All respected people like music artists and others.
        </li>
      </p>
    </ul>
    <h2>Further Explanation</h2>
    <p>We can clearly see that YouTube Shorts was created after TikTok. All the videos are also super boring and most of them use outdated memes. Check out this link for a comparison: 
      <a href="https://nationalpositions.com/youtube-shorts-vs-tiktok-whats-the-difference/">Comparison</a>. 
      There is a very nice video explaining if YouTube should stop makeing shorts. It gives opinions on both sides with clear and concise detail. Take a look: <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaETvTFJ4rc">Opinions.</a>
    </p>   
    </div>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That will only make the background white, not transparent.

Comment: Transparent meaning what? What are you expecting to see?

Comment: I still want to see the fixed background, and make the scrolling page transparent

Comment: check out my new answer. I believe I understand your problem now